What function has the Replication key in a SQL connection string
We are connecting to SQL Server in Azure.
Quite recently, my connections to the server where refused. Connections have been working fine for several years.
After some trial and error, we figured out that setting Replication=True allows the connection to be made. This can be configured as an option in the GUI when using Azure Data Studio, but needs to be set manually when connecting via Python or SSMS.
To repeat the question initially asked here, what does this parameter do? And what changes would cause the need to set this parameter?

Edit to include error message (2024-10-29 09:00 CET):
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)

What is exact error you're getting when connecting? Do you have some logon trigger?

Replication moves data in distributed environments ranging from intranets on a single domain to applications that access data between untrusted domains and over the Internet.
When you set Replication=True, it allows the connection to recognize and work with replication configurations.
This setting should be considered only if you are developing a custom "replication-like" that differs from the built-in replication methods, and you need to configure a connection for your customised connection.
Note: Enabling this parameter disables any constraint or trigger marked as NOT FOR REPLICATION for that specific connection.
Reference: Replication Security Best Practices
